# really confused about expected value

Tags: probability

The expected value of X is 1 and is the same as X's SD. The expected value of Ysquare is 3, the expected value of (Y+1)square equals to 4, the expected value of (X+Y)square is 7.
I got stuck at figuring out E(Y+1)square. 
any hint that can help me solve this?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a homework problem. However, let me summarize, you have:

- $E(Y^2)=3$
- $E((Y+1)^2)=4$

You search: $$(E(Y+1))^2 =? $$
Note that $$(Y+1)^2= Y^2+2Y+1.$$
Hence using the linearity of the expectation, i.e. the rule $E(aX+b) = aE(X)+b$, you may derive $E(Y)$ from your given values and finally derive $(E(Y+1))^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I can rewrite it as E(Y^2) + 2E(Y) + 1 = 4,  hence E(Y) = 0?

Comment: For E(X+Y)^2 = 7, I can rewrite it as E(X^2) +2E(X)E(Y) + E(Y^2) = 7?

Comment: your first comment is correct. your second comment is not correct.  You have  $E((X+Y)^2)= E(X^2+2XY+Y^2) = E(X^2)+ 2E(XY) +E(Y^2)$ and in general  $E(XY)\neq E(X)E(Y)$. However, you may derive $E(XY)$ from $$E((X+Y)^2) = E(X^2) + E(Y^2) + 2E(XY) = 7$$ you already know $E(Y^2)$. In order to calculate $E(X^2)$ use the identity $E(X^2) =Var(X) +E(X)^2$ and note that $\sqrt{Var(X)}=1$ holds if and only if $Var(X)=1$

Comment: Thank you very much! Your comment really helps me a lot!